# SQLite Temp view/table in background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, cocoa

I am creating a temp view/table on the database from one thread, I then try to access that temp table in a background thread and I can't access the temp tables. I understood that the same process could see the temp tables, but I can't, I get a no such table... in ...

How can I access temp views/tables from other threads, within the same process?

I am using blocks, and opening a new connection when the block executes, running the query/statements then closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary tables/views are local to the database connection.

You have to share a database connection (which would require additional synchronization), or [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) another database file with a known name in each connection.

Comment: I had this suspicion. Are there any other SQLite things that live only per connection?